# Can intuitionistic proofs be laid out in a format that parallels reductio ad absurdum?

Tags: logic

Suppose I want to prove $A \Rightarrow B$ using classical logic. I can structure my proof in the following way.

> Suppose not (If $A$, then $B$.)
>
> ---
>
> Then $A$, and not $B$.
>
> So...
>
> ...
>
> Therefore, contradiction.

Now the above approach isn't valid intuitionistically (because $\neg(A\Rightarrow B)$ does not necessarily imply $A \wedge \neg B$.) However, I was wondering if a similar approach can be used in intuitionistic proofs. I'm thinking that additionally to "not," we define a new operator "alternative-not," which allows us to argue as follows.

> Suppose alternative-not (If $A$, then $B$.)
>
> ---
>
> Then $A$, and alternative-not $B$.
>
> So...
>
> ...
>
> Therefore, we're done.

Does an operator "alternative-not" with the necessary properties exist?

Answer (score 2):

1) The main thing to say the canonical way of proving a conditional is **not**, repeat **not**, the round-the-houses route via reductio which you suggest, but (of course) simple Conditional Proof:

> $\quad\quad |\quad A \quad\quad\quad\mathrm{supposition}$
>
> $\quad\quad |\quad \vdots $
>
> $\quad\quad |\quad C$
>
> $A \to C \quad\quad\quad\quad\mathrm{discharge\ supposition}$

And this rule applies equally in intuitionistic logic.

2) Reductio in the form "If the supposition $A$ implies the absurdity $\bot$, then infer $\neg A$" **is**, repeat **is**, intuitionistically valid.

3) The move from not-(If A, then B) to A and not-B is not inituitionistically valid. One way to see why it isn't intuitionistically valid is to reflect how we warrant that move in a natural deduction setting?

> $\neg(A \to B)$
>
> $\quad | \quad \neg(A \land \neg B)$
>
> $\quad | \quad | \quad A$
>
> $\quad | \quad | \quad | \quad \neg B$
>
> $\quad | \quad | \quad | \quad (A \land\neg B)$
>
> $\quad | \quad | \quad | \quad \bot$
>
> $\quad | \quad | \quad \neg\neg B$
>
> $\quad | \quad | \quad B\quad\quad\quad$(DN)
>
> $\quad | \quad (A \to B)\quad\quad$(CP)
>
> $\quad | \quad \bot$
>
> $\neg\neg(A \land \neg B)$
>
> $(A \land \neg B)\quad\quad\quad$(DN)

This classical proof involves applications of the classical DN rule, so can't carry over to intuitionistic logic.

4) "Weak not"??? Since not-(If A, then B) to A and not-B is not intuitionistically valid, it looks more like you to introduce a *stronger* (indeed, classical!) not. What would the inference rules for this alternative negation be? How would it relate to the $\bot$ that appears in the essential intuitionistic rules (i) from $\bot$ infer anything, and (ii) reductio?

Comment: 4). I was thinking, for example: Suppose $A \Rightarrow B$, and alternative-not $B$. Then alternative-not $A$. Also: Suppose alternative not $A \Rightarrow B$. Then $A$, and alternative-not $B$.

Comment: How does it interact with $\bot$? We need a complete story.

Comment: Sorry Peter, I don't know. But I can explain the motivation. In 1), you proceed by $\rightarrow$ from $A$ to $C$. Alternatively, you could have proceeded by $\leftarrow$ from $C$ to $A$, if that makes sense. In classical logic at least, this latter proof would instead be transformed into a proof of the contrapositive. Begin with $\neg C$, and proceed by $\rightarrow$ to $\neg A$. Or, even more conveniently, we can begin with both $A$ and $\neg C$, and simply deduce a contradiction. I'm wanting the convenience of this latter approach, but I want it to work intuitionistically.

Comment: P.S. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Still not clear. For a start, contraposition in the form $A \to C$ hence $\neg A \to \neg C$ **is** intuitionistically valid.

Comment: So there's two approaches. Proceed from $A$ to $C$, or proceed from $\neg C$ to $\neg A$. But what if I want to mix the approaches, and in some sense "meet in the middle"? In classical logic, we can proceed from $A \wedge \neg C$ to a contradiction.

Comment: I think the short answer is no, but I don't see how to justify it. It is probably related to the reason why intuitionistic sequent calculus only allows one formula on the right of the turnstile.

Answer (score 2):

An identity is true in all Heyting algebras if and only if it is true in the algebra of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. In this algebra, $U \wedge V= U \cap V$, $U \vee V= U \cup C$, $\neg U = \text{ext}(U)$ (the exterior of $U$), $U \to V = \text{int}(U^c \cap V)$, and $(U \leq V) = (U \subseteq V)$

As first-order intuitionistic logic is complete, the validity of any argument can be checked by looking at truth values.

For the purposes of finding counter-examples, you should remove interior points from your open sets. e.g. it's not too hard to show

$$ \neg \neg U = \text{int}(\overline{U}) $$

Reasoning topologically, it seems unlikely that anything of the sort you want is possible without expanding the set of truth values.

e.g. $U \to V$ remembers the "holes" in $V$ that are away from $U$, but $\neg V$ has completely forgotten that information, and it is implausible that any open-set-valued operator can usefully retain that information in a complemented form.

---

Incidentally, RAA *is* valid in intuitionistic logic. If you suppose $P$ and derive a contradiction, then that means you've proven $P \to \bot$, which is equivalent to $\neg P$ (in fact, it's often taken as the *definition* of $\neg P$ in Heyting algebra). What *is* different is that $\neg \neg P$ does not always imply $P$.

However, an interesting feature of intuitionistic logic is that if you restrict yourself solely to working with negated propositions, the rules of deduction are identical to classical logic. e.g. $\neg\neg\neg P \to \neg P$ is a tautology. More generally, if $\neg P \to \neg Q$ is a tautology of classical logic, then it is automatically a tautology in intuitionistic logic too.